# giving a short name for frequently opened directory via terminal

Tags: command-line, directory

Every time I wish to move to a directory I use very often, I must type this long directory path:

```
cd /media/prasanth/01D0F888E7BC91801/github projects
```

or I must use the gui to get into the folder and open the terminal.

Is it possible to assign this long path to a single name and enter it via the terminal like

```
cd mygitfiles
```

?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use aliases. See `help alias`.

In a nutshell, you can define an alias by typing:

```
alias whatever="cd /media/prasanth/01D0F888E7BC91801/github/projects"
```

Then, typing `whatever` will move you to the defined folder.

You can put the alias command in your ~/.bashrc to keep it permanently.

Answer (score 20):

So far two great have been given in other answers, I have one more possibility:

```
ln -s /media/prasanth/01D0F888E7BC91801/github/projects ~/mygitfiles
```

Will create a symlink to the long path in your home.

Symlinks are like shortcuts that point to another file or directory, and most programs will treat them as normal.  you can safely `rm` the symlink without effecting the path it points to. you can observe where the symlink points to with `ls -l`.

You can use the symlink as if it was a real directory and do `cd ~/mygitfiles`.

Note that ~ is simply an alias for your home directory, which might be a sensible place for such a symlink.

Be aware that using this symlink ultimately effects your current working directory.

In the general case I would suggest Nicolas Delvaux, or Eduardo Cola's answer, but using a symlink might be just as - or possibly more useful.

Answer (score 10):

You can store your path in an environment variable. Run:

```
nano $HOME/.bashrc
```

Go to the end of the file, create a new line and write:

```
export mgf="/media/prasanth/01D0F888E7BC91801/github projects"
```

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to save the file. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit. Now log out and log in. When youn open a terminal (running bash) you can run `cd "$mgf"` to change to your directory.

Comment: There's no need to logout though. Either run `. ~/.bashrc` (if in the console or in a terminal) or close / reopen the terminal (if in a terminal).

Comment: There's no need for the sudo. It's your .bashrc, you should be able to edit it.

Comment: Good answer and this can work with subdirectories, like `cd $mgf/subdir/`. Upvoted

Comment: Putting this in `.bashrc` limits its usefulness to only bash shells, and is a waste of resources. There's no need to run this on every subshell invocation in `~/.bashrc`.  It should be in `~/.profile` so it is read by any login shell, as explained at [What are the functional differences between .profile .bash_profile and .bashrc - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/261802/what-are-the-functional-differences-between-profile-bash-profile-and-bashrc)

Answer (score 9):

It seems like you're looking for [cdargs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/cdargs.1.html).

It provides bookmarks for the `cd` command.

You can add a bookmark by executing `mark NAME` in the directory that is bookmarked. Then you can change to this directory from anywhere using `cv NAME` with NAME being the name of the bookmark.

Comment: Wow. My life just got that much easier. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You could have a look at [`autojump`](https://github.com/wting/autojump).
It basically learns as you use `cd` by building a database of folders you visit and assigning weights to them: the more you visit a folder, the higher it is in the database.

Then, after you `cd` a few times to a directory (even once suffices):

```
cd /media/prasanth/01D0F888E7BC91801/github projects
```

you can jump there by using the `j` command:

```
j proj
```

You can use any part of the directory name as an argument to the `j` command and it will jump to the first entry that matches, so that's helpful when you don't remember the full path.

It has some other capabilities which are pretty neat such as **jump to child** (`jc`). I encourage you to inspect it.

Comment: I use `autojump`, and it works well. The best thing is that it learns from your use. I didn't know about `jc`, so that's something for me to look at.

Answer (score 3):

Bash has a handy little misfeature called `CDPATH`. When `cd foo` looks for a relative path, it looks in the current directory by default. By setting `CDPATH` to a colon-separated list of path prefixes, we can go to that target instead if no match was found. This works similarly to the `PATH` variable when looking for executable files.

In your case, you could `export CDPATH=.:/media/prasanth/01D0F888E7BC91801/github/` in your `~/.bashrc`, and then execute `cd projects/foo` from anywhere to get to `/media/prasanth/01D0F888E7BC91801/github/projects/foo`.

However, this will not work if your current directory contains a matching entry, so this can have some confusing error modes. There are some people that swear by this methods, I myself rather prefer [symlinks in the home directory](https://askubuntu.com/a/716880/150675) as suggested by Paul Grove.

Answer (score 2):

I would type

```
cd /media/prasanth/01D0F888E7BC91801/github projects #demo-proj
```

the first time I run that command. The content after # is a comment.

Then to call it, I would <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and type in `de` (a convenient substring of `demo-proj`), till the previous command comes up.

```
(reverse-i-search)`de': cd /media/prasanth/01D0F888E7BC91801/github projects #demo-proj
```

I can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> again for even-earlier uses.

---

This has no need to set/replace permanent aliases. I also do this for long commands or even `netstat -tulpn` which I find cryptic.