# Shorter name for my home directory

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-mate

I have 2 versions of Ubuntu-Mate, 18.04 and 20.04.

This is my home directory for 20.04.

```
/media/andy/81353260-b5a5-4b72-9fce-432e7c620fdc/home/andy/

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=5b4b2ae5-9aaa-4559-9f41-afb313998c75 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Is there a way I can change the name to a more user friendly and shorter name.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the output of `cat /etc/fstab` please

Comment: Consider [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/716880/307670) to a similar question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [giving a short name for frequently opened directory via terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716795/giving-a-short-name-for-frequently-opened-directory-via-terminal)

Comment: @Nicolas Formichella I edited my post.

Comment: @24601 I prefer renaming the directory.

Comment: that looks like an accident, since your home partition is mounted on media. Default would be `/home/andy`. Something goofed up your installation. And: **DO NOT RENAME IT** because the system relies on that path. Much easier is to create a new user. It will reside in /home/xxxx

Comment: @kanehekili OP is double booting 20.04 with 18.04, this name seems to be the the 20.04 home directory but mounted within 18.04 (correct me if I'm wrong @fixit7)

Comment: @Nicolas Formichella why not having two partions? This way seems to be trouble prone

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and add the output of `ls -la /home`.

Comment: My home dir for 18.04 is /home/andy/. @Nicolas Formichella

Comment: Generally best not to share a /home partition. When upgrading, applications may update settings in /home for new versions. But then old versions in the old install may not work. If you want to have two installs, use separate /home but have a third data partition with all the data normally in your data folders like Documents, Downloads, etc. Also best to label partitions so automounts are by label (do not use home) but not by UUID (the long number).

Comment: I have 2 separate home directories. /media/andy/81353260-b5a5-4b72-9fce-432e7c620fdc/home/andy/ and /home/andy/ @oldfred

Comment: Still prefer separate data partition, but you can label partitions and then they are mounted by label. `lsblk -o name,fstype,size,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid | egrep -v "^loop"` To add labels, I often use Disks.  You can also use terminal. I added groovy to sdb8 with this `sudo e2label /dev/sdb8 groovy`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short-cut for switching to a given directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226417/short-cut-for-switching-to-a-given-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run

- `lsblk` to spot which partition holds the `20.04` install
- `blkid /dev/[what you found with sd* or nvme*n*p*]` and copy the entire `UUID=xx` string (including the `UUID=` part)
- `mkdir` whatever folder name you want in the `/media/andy` folder (ex. `mkdir /media/andy/2004`)
- `sudo nano /etc/fstab`
- Get at the end of the file and paste what I wrote in the code block and replace the `UUID=` and `/media/andy/` part with yours

```
UUID=xxxxxx /media/andy/  ext4 rw,nofail,nosuid,nouser,auto,exec user 0 0
```

See `man 5 fstab` and `man 8 mount` to find docs about what I did

Reboot and normally you should be able to `cd` to your new directory and have your partition mounted

Answer (score 1):

You could create an symlink in the `/home` directory of your 20.04 installation.

```
sudo ln -s /media/andy/81353260-b5a5-4b72-9fce-432e7c620fdc/home/andy /home/andy_1804
```

Then simply access your 18.04 "`home`" folder by using the shorter path "`/home/andy_1804`".

Answer (score 0):

The reason I wanted a shorter name for my home directory is I thought I would have to change some aliases that change directories.

```
One alias was alias dwn='cd /home/andy/Downloads'
```

But the actual directory is

```
/media/andy/81353260-b5a5-4b72-9fce-432e7c620fdc/home/andy/Downloads/
```

But the alias still works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Go to settings and then about. Change the Device Name and voilà.